Setting a transparent background on bulma hero?
How to set the background colour of a hero element in Bulma to transparent?
Version 1 of Bulma

Set the $primary variable?

This doesn't work.
$primary: transparent;
@use "../../../../libraries/node_modules/bulma/sass" with (
   $primary:v.$primary,


Set the specific hero values. This does not work, there is an error indicating that these variables can't be overridden as they don't have an exclamation mark.
@use '../../../../sites/variables' as v;
@use "../../../../libraries/node_modules/bulma/sass" with (
  $bulma-hero-s: v.$bulma-hero-s,


Override the css variables?


This works, but seems untidy. Certainly needs bulma internal details to work
.hero.is-primary {
  --bulma-hero-background-l: transparent;
}


Use CSS?

Also seems untidy
body  .hero.is-primary {
  background-color: transparent;
}

What is the cleanest way? The way that preserves the internal structure of Bulma?

From the demo on the Bulma documentation, it seems you can just use the class hero without adding specificity with is-primary.
